# Write a lock free singleton factory using generics in c#

Tags: c#, generics

I am writing a generic CacheProvider factory which contains a concurrent dictionary to keep the "Named" cache objects (a custom implementation of memory cache based on concurrent dictionary) to be shared among different state machines/pipelines.

I found this [article](http://public%20class%20CacheProvider%3CTKey,%20TType%3E%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20Eventing.Tracer%20tracer;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20delegate%20TType%20CreateObjectDelegate();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20readonly%20Dictionary%3CTKey,%20CreateObjectDelegate%3E%20FactoryMap;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20ConcurrentDictionary%3CTKey,%20TType%3E%20cachePool;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20private%20static%20object%20_lock%20=%20new%20object();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20///%20%3Csummary%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20///%20This%20class%20is%20a%20singleton%20wrapper%20on%20custom%20memory%20cache%20class%20to%20be%20shared%20with%20different%20state%20machines%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20///%20%3C/summary%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20///%20%3Cparam%20name=%22tracer%22%3E%3C/param%3E%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20CacheProvider(Eventing.Tracer%20tracer)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Contract.Requires%3CArgumentException%3E(tracer%20!=%20null,%20%22tracer%20cannot%20be%20null%22);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.tracer%20=%20tracer;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cachePool%20=%20new%20ConcurrentDictionary%3CTKey,%20TType%3E();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FactoryMap%20=%20new%20Dictionary%3CTKey,%20CreateObjectDelegate%3E();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20TType%20GetMemoryCache(TKey%20key)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(cachePool.ContainsKey(key)%20&&%20cachePool[key]%20is%20TType%20memoryCache)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20memoryCache;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20default(TType);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20public%20TType%20CreateOrGetMemoryCache(TKey%20key)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20lock%20(_lock)%20//%20make%20sure%20this%20method%20is%20thread%20safe%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(cachePool.ContainsKey(key)%20&&%20cachePool[key]%20is%20TType%20memoryCache)%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20tracer.Trace(SplitterTraceCodes.CacheProvider,%20$%22MemoryCache%20with%20cache%20key:%20%7Bkey%7D%20already%20created.%22);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20memoryCache;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20else%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20tracer.Trace(SplitterTraceCodes.CacheProvider,%20$%22MemoryCache%20with%20cache%20key:%20%7Bkey%7D%20not%20found.%22);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20//%20Create%20a%20new%20one%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20CreateObjectDelegate%20constructor%20=%20null;%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20(FactoryMap.TryGetValue(key,%20out%20constructor))%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cachePool[key]%20=%20constructor();%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20cachePool[key];%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20throw%20new%20ArgumentException(%22Error%20in%20Creating%20MemoryCache.%20No%20Type%20registered%20for%20this%20Cache%20Key%22);%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%7D) and came up with below implementation

```
public class CacheProvider<TKey, TType>
{
    private Eventing.Tracer tracer;
    public delegate TType CreateObjectDelegate();
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, CreateObjectDelegate> FactoryMap;
    private ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TType> cachePool;
    private static object _lock = new object();

    /// <summary>
    /// This class is a singleton wrapper on custom memory cache class to be shared with different state machines
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="tracer"></param>
    public CacheProvider(Eventing.Tracer tracer)
    {
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentException>(tracer != null, "tracer cannot be null");
        this.tracer = tracer;
        cachePool = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TType>();
        FactoryMap = new ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, CreateObjectDelegate>();
    }

    public void Register(TKey key, CreateObjectDelegate ctor)
    {
     // This method registers a delegate to the method used to create the 
       object so that it can be created later.
       //
      FactoryMap.TryAdd(key, ctor);
    }

    public TType CreateOrGetMemoryCache(TKey key)
    {
            if (cachePool.TryGetValue(key, out TType memoryCache))
            {
                tracer.Trace(SplitterTraceCodes.CacheProvider, $"MemoryCache with cache key: {key} already created.");
                return memoryCache;
            }
            else
            {
                tracer.Trace(SplitterTraceCodes.CacheProvider, $"MemoryCache with cache key: {key} not found.");

                // Create a new one
                CreateObjectDelegate constructor = null;
                if (FactoryMap.TryGetValue(key, out constructor))
                {
                    cachePool.TryAdd(key,constructor());
                    cachePool.TryGetValue(key, out TType memoryCache);
                    return memoryCache;
                }

                throw new ArgumentException("Error in Creating MemoryCache. No Type registered for this Cache Key");
            }
    }
}
```

TType is as follows:

```
MyBase 
{
  string BaseProperty1;
} 
MyChild1 : MyBase
{
  string ChildProperty1;
}
MyChild2 : MyBase
{
 string ChildProperty2;
}
```

I am looking to setup this at service startup as follows:

```
CacheProvider<string, object> cacheProvider= new CacheProvider<string, object>();
CacheProvider<string, object>.CreateObjectDelegate createCacheForMyChild1 = new CacheProvider<string, object>.CreateObjectDelegate(CustomConcurrentCache<string,MyChild1>());
CacheProvider<string, object>.CreateObjectDelegate createCacheForMyChild2 = new CacheProvider<string, object>.CreateObjectDelegate(CustomConcurrentCache<string,MyChild2>());
cacheProvider.Register("MyChild1Cache", createCacheForMyChild1 );
cacheProvider.Register("MyChild2Cache", createCacheForMyChild2 );
```

and use it wherever I need the named cache instance:

```
CustomConcurrentCache<string,MyChild1> cache =  (MyChild1)cacheProvider.CreateOrGetMemoryCache<object>("MyChild1Cache");
```

Can this be done without using the delegates? Is there any other better way to achieve this?

Comment: Hope this is the right place where this question can be answered. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

A delegate can be seen as method signature contract. You can define what sort of methods are you willing to work with. For example

- The method should accept type `x`, type `y` and type `z` as parameters
- and should return with type `w`

Any method, which satisfy this contract, is a valid method from the delegate perspective.

---

```
public delegate TType CreateObjectDelegate();
```

This delegate says that any method that has no parameter and will return with TType is a good one.

You can describe the same by using the `Func` class:

```
Func<TType> CreateObjectDelegate
```

Whenever you want to call the `Register` method you just have to pass a method which satisfies this contract. For example (let's suppose `TType` is `int`):

```
cacheProvider.Register("MyChild1Cache", () => 0);

Func<int> alternative1 = () => 1;
cacheProvider.Register("MyChild2Cache", alternative1.Invoke);

Func<int, Func<int>> alternative2 = i => () => i;
cacheProvider.Register("MyChild3Cache", alternative2.Invoke(2).Invoke);
```